# SSRS showing different data in reportserver and Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In Microsoft Visual Studio when i run a Report using a Preview the data is showing  and when the same report i run from server side its not showing the same data as per the Visual Studio Preview

please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio caches locally data in order to reduce the generation time for design puroposes, it will only update the data if you change the parameters values so if your report doesn't have any parameter you will get old data.

To refresh Visual Studio data preview the report and press the refresh button inside the generated report.

Let me know if this can help you.

Comment: I also try this by refreshing the Preview but not showing data as per the ReportServer

Comment: Did you deploy the same datasource to the server? If your deployed report is using a different datasource with different settings it could causing the data discrepancies.

Comment: yes i deploy using the same datasourse to the server,now again i deploy the Report but still showing different data in  ReportServer

Comment: In Visual Studio go to `Project` / `Project Properties`  In `Deployment` menu check if `OverwriteDataSets` and `OverwriteDataSources` properties are set to `true`, then check if the problem persists.

Comment: The data caches exist in the project files as `.rdl.data` files. You can delete them manually in your file browser, or you can set up a tool that will  clear all data caches in a project (http://jasonfaulkner.com/ClearDataCacheBIS.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem. When I previewed on VS 2015, everything displayed perfect, but when I deployed to my server successfully, only one field wasn't showing up.

What ended up working was changing my report data sets from shared to embedded. Even though they were referencing the same query, somehow there was a disconnect when referencing the shared data set rather than embedding it directly in the report.